# error getting path returned rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes, nested-forms

I'm trying to access my page gallery/new via a link, so i have created this

```
<%= link_to 'New gallery' new_gallery_path %>
```

rake routes gives

```
gallery_index_path   GET     /gallery(.:format)  gallery#index
                     POST    /gallery(.:format)  gallery#create
new_gallery_path     GET     /gallery/new(.:format)  gallery#new
edit_gallery_path    GET     /gallery/:id/edit(.:format)     gallery#edit
gallery_path         GET     /gallery/:id(.:format)  gallery#show
                     PATCH   /gallery/:id(.:format)  gallery#update
                     PUT     /gallery/:id(.:format)  gallery#update
                     DELETE  /gallery/:id(.:format)  gallery#destroy
```

and within my routes i have

```
resources :gallery
```

My view at gallery/new is

```
<%= nested_form_for @gallery, :html => { :multipart => true} do |f| %>
--content here
<% end %>
```

whenever i click the link to view this page i get

```
undefined method `galleries_path
```

Can someone point out my mistake, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've chosen the wrong name for your `resources`. It should always be pluralized:

```
resources :galleries
```

From this Rails will generate the plural and singular paths correctly. `galleries_path` for the index, `gallery_path` for show, etc etc.